# Total War Shogun 2 : stuck on Splash screen

Tags: technical-issues, shogun-2-total-war

This problem has been bugging me for the best part of half a year now, resulting in me not being able to play one of my favourite games. It all happened around the time I got the DLC for Fall Of The Samurai.

**Problem**

- Click on icon to launch Total War Shogun 2 in Steam
- Game asks to start in Direct X mode (Dx9 or Dx10 is enabled)
- Select either one and the game loads to the Loading / Legal screen.
- Wait for 10 minutes and the game is still on that screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to desktop and see that "Shogun 2 is not responding" in task manager.

**Computer Specs**
(DxDiag)

http://pastebin.com/fi77nTaf

**Things I have tried**

- Updated Sound and Graphics drivers
- Updated BIOS for motherboard to latest version (1.2)
- Reinstalled Shogun 2 on steam
- Verified Game integrity on steam
- Changed graphics cards
- Searched Registry for "Incredibar" malware , not found on system
- Disabled SLI on Nvidia control panel

All of these have not solved my problem.

I am really running out of ideas what to do here. It makes no sense why this does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with my motherboard's northbound chip set between the CPU and Memory.

A replacement of it along with a newer AMD Quad Core processor resolved my issue. I have used the same Memory and GPU.